# Method to increase the upper bound of a daterange by one day

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I would like to increase the upper bound of all entries in a daterange column with an exclusive upper bound ')'.  Either method of changing the upper bound to be inclusive or by adding one day to the upper bound works for me.

First attempt (to change the upper bound to be inclusive)

```
ALTER TABLE time
ALTER COLUMN timespan
TYPE daterange[]
USING timespan::daterange[];


ERROR: cannot cast type daterange to daterange[]
```

Second attempt (to add 1 day to the upper bound)

```
UPDATE time
SET timespan = daterange(lower(timespan),upper((timespan) +
interval '1 day'::date));


ERROR: cannot cast type interval to date
```

Comment: Why are you casting an `interval` to a `date`? That doesn't make sense. Just use `upper(timespan) + interval '1' day`

Comment: If i do that then I receive    ERROR: operator does not exist: daterange + interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`daterange[]` in your first try is an array of `daterange`. It is not a `daterange` with both bounds included. The inclusion or not of a bound is not part of the `range` types. It is part of its values. To change the upper bound:

```
update time
set timespan = daterange(lower(timespan)::date, upper(timespan)::date, '[]')
```

Notice the last parameter of the `daterange` constructor `'[]'`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT

To add 1 day to the upper bound just do as commented by @a_horse

```
update time
set timespan = daterange(
    lower(timespan)::date, (upper(timespan) + interval '1 day')::date
)
```

Comment: I still receive an 'ERROR: function daterange (date, timestamp without time zone) does not exist'